# Waffle & font family not found in Windows font database

Tags: r, fonts, waffle-chart

I am trying to get the folowing code to work so that it will display the glyph medkit or any other icons from the FontAwesome font inside my waffle plot.

```
library(waffle)
library(extrafont)

font_import()


loadfonts(device = "postscript")
```

which does display Registering font with R using postscriptFonts(): FontAwesome

```
parts <- c(`Un-breached\nUS Population`=(318-11-79), `Premera`=11, `Anthem`=79)

waffle(parts/10, rows=3, colors=c("#969696", "#1879bf", "#009bda"),
   use_glyph="medkit", size=8)
```

When I run waffle I get the following errors:

Warning messages:

```
1: Removed 3 rows containing missing values (geom_text).

2: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :
font family not found in Windows font database
```

I just get a plot with boxes missing the icon inside them. What am I missing in my install of fontawesome or in my work inside RStudio?

Comment: [Some users report](https://nsaunders.wordpress.com/2017/09/08/infographic-style-charts-using-the-r-waffle-package/#comment-32153) that explicit font import can help: `font_import(pattern = “fontawesome-webfont.ttf”)`.

Comment: After going to the link provided by @neilfws I find a blog entitled "WHAT YOU'RE DOING IS RATHER DESPERATE" and I must predict that Tufte would be horrified. (Appears that this is a Windoze-only package.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the classic have you unplugged it and plugged it back in approach worked...I restarted RStudio and now it works.

Comment: Yup, how didn't i think of it before reading this still baffles me