# Font Awesome in R, loaded but not found by waffle

Tags: r, font-awesome, waffle-chart

I downloaded the otf files from [this website](https://fontawesome.com/?utm_source=font_awesome_homepage&utm_medium=display&utm_campaign=fa5_released&utm_content=download_modal). My IT dept installed "Font Awesome 5 Free Regular" and  I used

```
library(extrafont)
font_import()
loadfonts(device = "win")
```

I can see Font Awesome as "Font Awesome 5 Free Regular" is registered.
When I tried to use it with this test code:

```
waffle(c(50, 30, 15, 5), rows = 5, use_glyph = "music", glyph_size = 6)
```

I get

```
Error: FontAwesome not found. Install via: https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/tree/master/fonts
```

but that link doesn't go anywhere.

I would like to use Font Awesome (or a good alternative) to make interesting waffle charts.  Did I load the font incorrectly? Is there a better alternative I am missing?  I have been using this [article](https://nsaunders.wordpress.com/2017/09/08/infographic-style-charts-using-the-r-waffle-package/) as a guide. I have also read a related question here [on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49482512/waffle-font-family-not-found-in-windows-font-database), but it did not help.  I have restarted Rstudio (and the computer) several times and no luck.

**Update**

Still not working.  I have removed and reinstalled the waffle and emojifont packages. I Still get the error code : "Error: FontAwesome not found. Install via: https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/tree/master/fonts"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to use the font-awesome glyphs in `ggplot2` plots then you can use the wonderful `emojifont` package. No need to add the font manually yourself.

```
library("emojifont")
library("waffle")
waffle(c(50, 30, 15, 5), rows = 5, use_glyph = "music", glyph_size = 4)
```

That produces the graph you are after:

[image]

**Update:** Since you have installed the otf fonts and not the ttf fonts that might be the cause of your problems. The `load.fontawesome()` function in the `emojifont`package has a default argument:

```
load.fontawesome(font = "fontawesome-webfont.ttf")
```

You could try to 1) either install the ttf version of the fonts or 2) call

```
load.fontawesome(font = "fontawesome-webfont.otf")
```

before plotting (although I'm not sure the latter will work). Worth a try though.

Comment: I just tried emojifont and used the exact code here. I once again received the error code "Error: FontAwesome not found. Install via: https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/tree/master/fonts"

Comment: @Lauren I think the problem might be the otf-version of the font and not the ttf. I've updated my answer with another suggestion

Comment: the otf was the issue. You have to use the ttf found on github (though it isn't located at the address the error provides)       Now it is loaded, but I get dots, which is a step above the squares and error message I guess

Comment: This worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74589250/4438465

Answer (score 4):

I know this question was asked and answered quite a while ago, but the answer didn't help me with my code, and I found something that did from this source: https://www.listendata.com/2019/06/create-infographics-with-r.html
They have a step-by-step directions for downloading fontawesome using the extrafont library. Really easy. Hope this helps someone! Basically, download the fontawesome-webfont.ttf, then:

```
library(extrafont)
extrafont::font_import (path="C:/Users/insert/your/own/path", pattern = "awesome", prompt = FALSE)
loadfonts(device = "win")
# check to see if it works:
fonts()[grep("Awesome", fonts())]
#returns fontawesome
```

Then use `use_glyph =`  argument in making your waffle chart.

Comment: here, what really helped me is the use of `showtext::font_add` as suggested in that link. Thanks for pointing to the link

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who ends up here in 2021 and fails to get it working with `extrafont`, here is an alternative approach:

1. Use the legacy FontAwesome ttf, that [Silviculturalist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56890616/5356704) linked to:
   https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/releases/tag/v4.7.0
2. Extract `fontawesome-webfont.ttf` to your work directory (or some directory you can access)
3. Use the `waffle`, `emojifont` and `showtext` packages to create the chart, sample code below

```
install.packages(c("waffle", "emojifont", "showtext"))
 
library(waffle)
library(emojifont)
library(showtext)

font_add(family = "FontAwesome", 
         regular = "fontawesome-webfont.ttf")

waffle(c(5,12,18), rows = 5, use_glyph = "subway", glyph_size = 10, 
title = "Subways!", legend_pos="right")
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I tried to reproduce your detailed answer (1. Download v.4.7, 2 place it on the project's root, 3 load packages, 4, add font via showtext, 5 run your waffle code), but I get the same error as everyone else: "Error: Font [Font Awesome 5 Free Solid] not found. Please install it and use extrafont to make it available to R". You can check my sessioninfo() and code here: https://gist.github.com/ccamara/f85f3e5a8fb2be0d1a3d375a65ac5bb4 Do you happen to have any clue?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try using [FontAwesome v. 4.7](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/releases/tag/v4.7.0) I had the same issue as you but it resolved itself immediately when I installed the .ttf version.