# Waffle package on R icon

Tags: r, icons, waffle-chart

I'm trying to make a square pie with waffle function but the male icon can't be used

[image: that's what I get using the code below]

```
library(waffle) 
library(extrafont) 
parts <- c(`Sick=14` =14, `Treated=19` = 19, `Not sick=7` =7)

loadfonts(device = "win")
system.file("fonts", package="waffle")
waffle(
   parts, rows = 5, colors = c("#FD6F6F", "#93FB98", "#D5D9DD"),
   use_glyph = "male", size = 8 ,title = 'convenient title'
    )
```

Thank you .

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the same issue but this might help: https://github.com/hrbrmstr/waffle/issues/42

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely to a funky installation of Font Awesome. There are many version with various names around. Check that you have "FontAwesome" installed with the following command:

```
> fonts()[grep("Awesome", fonts())]

[1] "FontAwesome"
```

then you should be able to get this:

[image: convenient plot]

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was following all these instructions (https://www.listendata.com/2019/06/create-infographics-with-r.html) BUT installing the FontAwesome package 4.7 that you can download here (https://fontawesome.com/versions). Otherwise I think it seems newer packages have a different font/family name (Free Reegular version whatever) that waffle can not read.

I would say main points are:

- Add FontAwesome 4.7. font (.ttf) to your computer clicking on the .ttf file in the package once unzipped.
- Make sure you remove other versions of FontAwesome from your computer and from the fonttable of extrafont (https://stackoverflow.com/a/70386036/4438465)
- Make sure you also add the font with the font_add option in showtext package (see step 7 in the first link from listendata).