# Can not load Font Awesome in R and RStudio

Tags: r, waffle-chart

I'm following this instruction : [link](https://nsaunders.wordpress.com/2017/09/08/infographic-style-charts-using-the-r-waffle-package/)

and I have this code:

```
library(waffle)
library(extrafont)
font_import()

# use this if things look odd in RStudio under Windows
loadfonts(device = "win")

waffle(c(50, 30, 15, 5), rows = 5, use_glyph = "fa-car", glyph_size = 40,
title = "Look I made an infographic using R!")
```

And I get this as result:

*"Error: FontAwesome not found. Install via: https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/tree/master/fonts"*

I also check if I Font Awesome installed or not with this code:

```
# check that Font Awesome is imported
fonts()[grep("Awesome", fonts())]
```

and I received this message: 
*" [1](https://nsaunders.wordpress.com/2017/09/08/infographic-style-charts-using-the-r-waffle-package/) "Font Awesome 5 Brands" "Font Awesome 5 Free" "*

Comment: I've posted a solution here, using the `showtext` package: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68183288/5356704

Comment: After a lot of digging what worked for me is here, in case it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74589250/4438465

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is still an issue for you or not, but it certainly was for me, and I eventually got it to work! I think there's something in the package that's set up a bit too specifically for V4 of FontAwesome. The upgrade to V5 changes some naming conventions and in doing so, I'm pretty sure it's mucked around with the package.

Easiest solution? I just had to install v4 of FontAwesome. You can find it [here](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/).

With that installed, some combination of loading the libraries `emojifont` and `extrafont` got this working for me. Good luck!