# How to unregister removed fonts from R extrafontdb

Tags: r, extrafont

I have loaded my fonts using

```
library(extrafont)
font_import()
```

When I look at the path using

```
fonttable()
```

There are some fonts which does not exist any longer under that path. This creates some problems for me later on. How do I remove/unregister them from the font database?

Just rerunning font_import does not work.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy, just run the following code:

```
library(extrafont)    
db_path <- paste0(system.file(package = "extrafontdb"),"/fontmap/fonttable.csv")
file.show(db_path)
```

This opens up the .csv file that serves as the font database for `extrafont`. In this file you can just remove the fonts you want to unregister. Save the file when you're done and voilá!